# Как очистить окно в tkinter целиком одной командой?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как очистить окно в tkinter целиком одной командой? То есть не по одной кнопке ( кнопка.destroy()), а сразу одной командой.

Comment: Удали окно и создай новое

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45915006/11563491

Comment: Можно все содержимое окна создавать внутри Frame, потом одной командой удалить этот Frame.

Comment: Спасибо! ......